# trying to get the records only which are checked in vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am following this [library](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/checkbox) for checkboxes. I went to look down the code and I see how it's declared and used.

At first in `el-table` we have `@selection-change="handleSelectionChange"`. They have declared in data as empty array element like this

```
data() {
  retrun {
    multipleSelection: []
  }
}, 
methods:handleSelectionChange(val) {
  this.multipleSelection = val;
}
```

Now what I am checking is if I have some checkboxes clicked then I will get only those records not all. I am checking like this-

```
let data = []
console.log(this.multipleSelection.length);
if (this.multipleSelection.length == 0) {
    data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.myapidata));
} else {
    data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.multipleSelection));
}
```

But I am still getting complete data, not sure where I am missing the point. If anyone has experience in this, please guide.

Answer (score 0):

When you select the checkboxes, the `v-model` variable updates itself with the selected values and this is what two-way binding does. Console the `multipleSelection` inside your method-

```
methods: {
  handleSelectionChange() {
    // It will console only selected items
    console.log(this.multipleSelection);
  }
}
```

You should see that only selected items are available inside `multipleSelection`.